Adding new prospect to a list using API
I am writing some automation in Python to push prospects into a Pardot list. I thought the list endpoint would help me acheive this. But, it only gets the metadata of the list. Is there any endpoint that I could use to push the prospects directly into the list?

List Membership is what you are looking for.
Note that you can only use the API to add people to a Static List!
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/list-membership-v5.html#list-membership-create

Thanks so much. This worked!!
